# libwebsocket: test-server-echo fails with compiled library

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I compiled libwebsockets v1.7-stable with the following options:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/test -DLWS_WITH_ZLIB=0 -DLWS_WITHOUT_EXTENSIONS=1 -DLWS_WITH_SSL=0
```

When I tried to compile test-server-echo with this library, I've got the assertion failure on LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE:

```
 main.c:109: callback_echo: Assertion `(int)pss->len == -1' failed.
```

At the same time test-echo-server which was compiled with the library works smoothly. How can I fix this issue?

You can find the code here: http://pastebin.com/VMMhG4bP

Answer (score 0):

It might be a matter of library version. Try to compile and test with the last version [v2.0.0](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets)